# How can I remove all rows that have NA for a certain variable

Tags: r, dataframe, missing-data, weighted

My dataset ('data') has 1719 cases and 6779 variables. I need to weight the data using variable 'weight', however this is missing for 69 cases.

How can I delete the rows that have NA in the weight column, without deleting variables that have NA in any of the other 6778 columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my 'useful R commands' file ....

```
# drop a row with a NA value in a cell
df <- df[ !is.na(df$variable), ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Index rows by columns containing NA

```
data[!is.na(data[,"weight"]),]
```

Data frames are indexed using square braces to specify rows then columns separated by a comma: `data[rows, columns]`

You can then provide a vector of rows, using the `is.na` function and preceeded by the exclamation mark, making it effectively an is.*NOT*.na.

```
!is.na(data[,"weight"])
```